# How to find all the roads / streets / highways within a polynomial

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is a maps related question.

Summary: given a polynomial, I want to find all the roads / streets / highways within a polynomial.

The 'bounds' methodology does not seem to have  way where I can ask it to give me all the roads within that bound

Similarly, the co-ordinate+radius methodology gives all the places like schools, but there is no way to get all the streets within that range.

We have tried to do something by creating our own polynomial using 4 coordinates, and then trying to estimate the roads, but we are far from the result. So we feel we are in wrong direction all-together.

The URL of my experiment is here: http://prototype.nextgeni.us/polygon/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this data is exposed by the API.  What you're looking at is a collection of images with place names embedded into them.  The closest thing I can think of would be to use the DirectionsService, which does give you street names (but not in a useful format).  No idea how you could extend that to cover a whole polygon though, as it would just give you 1 route between markers, not all possible routes (and therefore not necessarily all streets in the polygon).